# Using Like with In to select query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, select

I have the query of the following which search the column request for xml for the matching string.

```
select * from Customer
where access like '%USR' 
and status = 'SUCCESS' 
and request like '%' || 
(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(request, '<paes:IdName>PurchaseId</paes:IdName><paes:IdValue>\d+</paes:IdValue>')  
FROM Customer
where request like '%Add%SUB%PRIME%') || '%';
```

however I am getting error message of `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

what I want is to search for the requests that has the same Id as the add but it is not an add request. For example....canceling order request with the Id number that used to canceling the order.

How do I change the above use request so it would take `like` `in` '%' || ... || '%'

or alternative for the above query?

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(request, '<paes:IdName>PurchaseId</paes:IdName><paes:IdValue>\d+</paes:IdValue>')  
    FROM Customer
    where request like '%Add%SUB%PRIME%'
```

would return multiple rows of Ids

what I want is to search all request column with matching Ids. If I replace `like` with `in` I would get `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB` error. How do I work around with this?

Edit:
example request column

```
Request
(HUGECLOB)
(HUGECLOB)
(HUGECLOB)
...
```

If I double click the HUGECLOB I would get the full request which is something like below....

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                wsu:Id="uuid_86c8ee4f-b6e6-4e07-9fa6-e2f9f2695c01">
                <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password
                    Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mx9483</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     ....
    <paes:IdName>PurchaseId</paes:IdName>
    <paes:IdValue>2786872</paes:IdValue>
     ....
    <paes:IdName>MailAddressId</paes:IdName>
    <paes:IdValue>2786622</paes:IdValue>
     ....
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Here is an example of cancel request

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                wsu:Id="uuid_86c8ee4f-b6e6-4e07-9fa6-e2f9f2695c01">
                <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password
                    Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mx9483</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <paes:IdName>CancelId</paes:IdName>
    <paes:IdValue>2786872</paes:IdValue>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: In your request also should be namespace for paes. xml tag with xmlns:paes= "blbleb".

Comment: yes there is but it was long...and under <SOAP-ENV:Body> I dont want to add the entire request here it would be too long. xmlns:paes="http://emvin.atl/schema/v1

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward. You can't use a subquery in a LIKE operator. I would also advice you to use a xml parse to get those ids and use it as a field with IN operator. See it [here] (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions051.htm) I will not provide an answer because I do not have an oracle environment to test the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Because sopa message is normal xml document. It's can by processed in  more stuctural way.

Prepare test DB;

```
create table rr (id number, requext clob) ;
```

Short version of messages.

```
insert into rr values(1, '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:paes="emvin.atl/schema/v1">
      <paes:IdName>PurchaseId</paes:IdName>
      <paes:IdValue>2786872</paes:IdValue>
      <paes:IdName>MailAddressId</paes:IdName>
      <paes:IdValue>2786622</paes:IdValue>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>');
insert into rr values(2, '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body  xmlns:paes="emvin.atl/schema/v1">
    <paes:IdName>CancelId</paes:IdName>
    <paes:IdValue>2786872</paes:IdValue>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>');
```

With xmltable function we can extract paes:IdValue.

```
select * from rr,xmltable( xmlnamespaces('emvin.atl/schema/v1' as "paes"), '$doc//paes:IdValue' passing xmltype(rr.requext) as "doc" 
columns  IdValue  number path './text()'
) ;
```

Now you can create view from previous query or just use it in with statement.

```
with test as (
select * from rr,xmltable( xmlnamespaces('emvin.atl/schema/v1' as "paes"), '$doc//paes:IdValue' passing xmltype(rr.requext) as "doc" 
columns  IdValue  number path './text()'
)) 
select * from test where IdValue in (select IdValue from test where id =1) 
 and id != 1;
```

[xquery](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xquery_intro.asp)

[xmltable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions240.htm)

Comment: I tried but it seems oracle cannot execute this from above. after alter the query of the similar format.

Comment: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: `columns  IdValue  number path './text()`' change `number` to `varchar2(100)`

Comment: now i got another error with:

ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 'R'
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1